# How can I fit a cosine function to 2D data?

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

Analysing some data, I produced the following curve which I need to fit to a trigonometric function (cosine).

[image: curve]

In Matlab, how can I get the parameters of the cosine function to best fit this data? x axis is the angle and y axis is Temperature. Thanks a lot.

EDIT: my data:

```
angle = [
0
3.316287766
4.730800754
9.134775894
11.91995938
13.21180064
16.97962712
20.87805072
22.34754865
24.61618179
28.18653577
31.58045095
35.07799869
38.5496595
41.97293968
44.56839009
45.3302489
46.10645938
48.67064021
52.08302411
55.54965999
59.04755401
62.28433855
65.72402163
68.63018998
69.36548262
73.19888377
76.8932392
78.40386372
80.91798834
85.28633489
86.74398825
90
]

Temperature = [
998.208
998.35
998.402
998.525
998.604
998.631
998.699
998.776
998.802
998.818
998.842
998.878
998.9
998.92
998.936
998.949
998.946
998.949
998.936
998.918
998.897
998.873
998.837
998.81
998.79
998.777
998.698
998.626
998.595
998.524
998.4
998.348
998.208
]
```

Comment: Sharing your data would be really helpful...

Comment: The `lsqnonlin` function should be a good choice for this, if your model is `y = A cos(Bx + C) + D`.   If you're sure `x` is equal to the angle not just related to it, then `y = A cos(pi * x / 180) + D` can be solved using a matrix pseudoinverse.  But just looking at your data, there should be some transformation between `x` and angle.

Comment: I have added the data. Apologies for the formatting, this is my first post. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
% Define the sample data and auxiliary variables...
x = [0 3.316287766 4.730800754 9.134775894 11.91995938 13.21180064 16.97962712 20.87805072 22.34754865 24.61618179 28.18653577 31.58045095 35.07799869 38.5496595 41.97293968 44.56839009 45.3302489 46.10645938 48.67064021 52.08302411 55.54965999 59.04755401 62.28433855 65.72402163 68.63018998 69.36548262 73.19888377 76.8932392 78.40386372 80.91798834 85.28633489 86.74398825 90];
y = [998.208 998.35 998.402 998.525 998.604 998.631 998.699 998.776 998.802 998.818 998.842 998.878 998.9 998.92 998.936 998.949 998.946 998.949 998.936 998.918 998.897 998.873 998.837 998.81 998.79 998.777 998.698 998.626 998.595 998.524 998.4 998.348 998.208];
p2 = 2 * pi();

% Determine the range of X...
x_max = max(x);
x_min = min(x);
x_range = linspace(x_min,x_max);

% Determine the scale of Y...
y_max = max(y);
y_mean = mean(y); 
y_range = y_max - min(y);

% Find the zero crossings...
yz = y - y_max + (y_range / 2);
zc = x(yz(:) .* circshift(yz(:),[1 0]) <= 0);

% Define the fitting and the LS functions...
fit = @(b,x) (b(1) .* (sin(((p2 * x) ./ b(2)) + (p2 / b(3))))) + b(4);
ls = @(b) sum((fit(b,x) - y) .^ 2);

% Minimize the LS...
ls_min = fminsearch(ls,[y_range; (2 * mean(diff(zc)));  -1;  y_mean]);

% Plot the result...
plot(x,y,'b');
hold on;
plot(x_range,fit(ls_min,x_range),'r');
hold off;
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using [`fitnlm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitnlm.html):

```
% your "data"
a=[0 3.316287766 4.730800754 9.134775894 11.91995938 13.21180064 16.97962712 20.87805072 22.34754865 24.61618179 28.18653577 31.58045095 35.07799869 38.5496595 41.97293968 44.56839009 45.3302489 46.10645938 48.67064021 52.08302411 55.54965999 59.04755401 62.28433855 65.72402163 68.63018998 69.36548262 73.19888377 76.8932392 78.40386372 80.91798834 85.28633489 86.74398825 90 ];
T=[998.208 998.35 998.402 998.525 998.604 998.631 998.699 998.776 998.802 998.818 998.842 998.878 998.9 998.92 998.936 998.949 998.946 998.949 998.936 998.918 998.897 998.873 998.837 998.81 998.79 998.777 998.698 998.626 998.595 998.524 998.4 998.348 998.208 ];

F=@(b,data) b(1)+b(2)*cosd(b(3)*data+b(4)); % the fitting function
b0=[T(1),1,1,0]; % initial guess for the fit

opts = statset('maxIter',500,'TolFun',1e-6); % controlling the fit options
mdl=fitnlm(a,T,F,b0,'Options',opts); % doing the fit
coeff=mdl.Coefficients.Estimate; % the fit coefficients (b)
plot(a,T,'o'); hold on % lets see how we did...
plot(a,F(coeff,a),'--')
```

[image]